# HTTP/2 Outbound support from Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, http2, squid

We have requirement where we have to access some external APIs that are exposed to   HTTP/2 (only) from our microservices (EKS kubernetes cluster, Perl based) through SQUID Proxy.

It seems, SQUID proxy doesn't support HTTP/2 so we are trying to get some alternative solution like:

1. Different proxy to support HTTP/2 outbound call
2. Or convert HTTP1.1 to HTTP/2

Could someone suggest the best alternative as per their experience on this and let me know the proxy information which will work in this scenario?

Many Thanks in advance.